# How to check for Super-Linter errors before pushing to the remote branch?

Tags: python, pycharm, lint, super-linter

When I push code for a new feature, Super-Linter checks the entire code. If there are any violations, I need to check the GitHub PR page, which can be quite annoying. I want to be able to know about these violations before pushing to the remote branch.

When using PyCharm, is it possible to know about these lint violations in real-time, similar to the way Pylint warnings are underlined?

And if this isn't possible, are there any other methods available, such as running Super-Linter locally or using some plugins?

I have tried adding Super-Linter as an external tool in PyCharm, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Git hooks. Typically one would have precommit hook to prevent even committing to local branch if linting fails.

Answer (score 3):

To utilize Super-Linter locally, you can use Docker. Assuming your project is located at `C:\projects\projectname`, you can execute a command like the following:

```bash
docker run --rm -e RUN_LOCAL=true -v C:/projects/projectname:/tmp/lint github/super-linter
```

Make sure to modify the [environmental variables](https://github.com/github/super-linter/blob/main/README.md#Environment-variables) as needed to meet your specific requirements.

---

Indicative output:

```
2023-04-21 10:08:44 [INFO]   File:[/tmp/lint/app/static/js/buttons.js]
------
/tmp/lint/app/static/js/buttons.js:6:1: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression. (no-unused-expressions)
/tmp/lint/app/static/js/buttons.js:6:2: Wrap an immediate function invocation in parentheses. (wrap-iife)

2023-04-21 09:47:25 [ERROR]   ERRORS FOUND in CSS:[3]
2023-04-21 09:47:25 [ERROR]   ERRORS FOUND in DOCKERFILE_HADOLINT:[1]
2023-04-21 09:47:25 [ERROR]   ERRORS FOUND in GITHUB_ACTIONS:[2]
2023-04-21 09:47:25 [ERROR]   ERRORS FOUND in HTML:[1]
2023-04-21 09:47:25 [ERROR]   ERRORS FOUND in JAVASCRIPT_STANDARD:[1]
2023-04-21 09:47:25 [ERROR]   ERRORS FOUND in MARKDOWN:[3]
2023-04-21 09:47:25 [ERROR]   ERRORS FOUND in PYTHON_BLACK:[3]
2023-04-21 09:47:26 [ERROR]   ERRORS FOUND in PYTHON_ISORT:[3]
2023-04-21 09:47:26 [ERROR]   ERRORS FOUND in YAML:[6]
2023-04-21 09:47:26 [FATAL]   Exiting with errors found!
```